# Existence: non-recursive sequence without a recursive subsequence

Tags: logic, computability

As the title suggests, the question is whether or not there exists a non-recursive sequence of natural numbers which has no recursive subsequence?

Comment: The busy beaver sequence can be said to be non-recursive *because* it grows too fast. Any subsequence thereof grows too fast as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sufficiently fast-growing function (such as the Busy Beaver function) provides an example. However, there's also a cute general trick we can use here:

Given an **arbitrary** sequence of natural numbers $\alpha=(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, consider the new sequence $$\hat{\alpha}=(\prod_{k<i}p_k^{a_k+1})_{i\in\mathbb{N}},$$ where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime. Each term in the sequence $\hat{\alpha}$ codes an entire initial segment of $\alpha$; if I know infinitely many terms of $\hat{\alpha}$ I can reconstruct the entire sequence $\alpha$. This means that if $\alpha$ is any noncomputable sequence, then $\hat{\alpha}$ is a noncomputable sequence with no computable subsequence. Moreover, $\alpha$ and $\hat{\alpha}$ are "essentially equally complicated" (precisely: $\alpha\equiv_T\hat{\alpha}$), so this shows that sequences without computable subsequences are quite common.

Comment: How is the equivalence relation $\equiv_T$ defined formally?

Comment: @Jean-PierredeVilliers See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction). "$X\equiv_TY$" means "$X\le_TY$ and $Y\le_TX$."